# how to use different configuration files during deployment of react js app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, react-hooks

I have 3 environments and I am using Sharepoint as backend. Each environment has got fields which are called differently. The problem is that I can't change the internal names of these fields.

I am using REST API to call SharePoint endpoints as follows:

```
/sites/someSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select=field1,field2[etc]
```

In my `react app`, I would like to achieve the following:

1. store this relative url `/sites/someSite` somewhere at the root of the application and access it everywhere in the application
2. each environment has some fields which differ in name, for example:

- dev: field1
- acc: field1 is called col1
- prod: field1 is called fieldCol1
  etc

these fields are used in my rest api queries.

```
How can I configure my application so that during deployment, a configration file can be
 used or some other means to assign the correct fields to each REST API call?
```

I can use sort of if else branch, but that does not seem realistic.

Dev:

```
/sites/someSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select=field1,field2,field3,field4, etc
```

Acc:

```
/sites/someSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select=col1,field2,col3,field4, etc
```

Prod:

```
/sites/someSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select=fieldCol1,fieldCol2,field3,field4, etc
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you can maintsin 3 seperate configuration/env files for your application (dev.env, ...). First instlall using npm  `dotenv` and `env-cmd` dependencies. Add following script to the package json file.

```
    scripts": {
        "start:dev": "env-cmd -f dev.env npm start" 
        "start:prod": "env-cmd -f prod.env npm start"
...
}
```

If you want to start react app using dev environment. You can use

```
npm run start:prod
```

Then mentioned url like below.

`"/sites/someSite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select="+ SELECT`

You can use `require('dotenv').config()` to read the environments.

dev.env file like below.

```
SELECT = col1,col2...
```